# How can make a mapping that comments N lines of code up or down in vim like "cm6j" where cm stands for comment?

Tags: vim

Hey I'm learning vim script and I wonder how can I emulate the vim style of commands like "d4k" to delete 4 lines above, but with my own custom "things to do". Also I want it to put my cursor back where it was, something like

```
nnoremap cm ma^i//<Esc>`a "for commenting
nnoremap ucm ma^d2l`a "for uncommenting
```

So cm6j should comment the current line and 6 below it and go back to where I was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `g@` to define a custom operator. If you read through [`:h g@` it will give a good example](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/map.html#g@) that explains how to do it. I came up with this:

```
function! Comment(type, ...) range
  normal m`
  if a:0
    silent exe "'<,'>normal! I//"
  else
    silent exe "'[,']normal! I//"
  endif

  exec "normal \<C-o>"
endfunction

nnoremap cm :set opfunc=Comment<cr>g@
xnoremap cm :call Comment(visualmode(), 1)<cr>

function! Uncomment(type, ...) range
  normal m`
  if a:0
    silent exe "'<,'>normal! ^2x'["
  else
    silent exe "'[,']normal! ^2x"
  endif

  exec "normal \<C-o>"
endfunction

nnoremap ucm :set opfunc=Uncomment<cr>g@
xnoremap ucm :call Uncomment(visualmode(), 1)<cr>
```

As a side note, I'd recommend picking a different mnemonic for uncommenting, since with `ucm`, if you try to use u for *undo*, you'll have to wait a little bit to see the effects.

Additionally, you could install the [NERD commenter](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdcommenter) plugin.

Comment: This is correct, using `g@` and `'opfunc'` is the proper way to create a vim operator (See `:h operator`). I would also recommend taking a look at [commentary.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-commentary/blob/master/plugin/commentary.vim) plugin by Tim Pope. It should be a good example. I would also recommend using a [comment plugin](http://vimawesome.com/?q=comment) instead of reinventing one, unless this is a purely educational exercise. Here is [naive commentary-like clone](https://gist.github.com/PeterRincker/13bde011c01b7fc188c5) I did as an exercise.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use my tiny [NiceComment](https://github.com/nicollet/nicecom.vim) plugin.

Install it, then update your .vimrc as suggested on the homepage.
Then assuming that your leader key is spacebar:

`6<space>cc` to comment and `6<space>cu` to uncomment.

Moreover, you can simply select some text with 'v' key and then press `cc` to comment, or `cu` to uncomment.

It is a bit more useful IMHO than most of the other plugins because it only comments whole lines, and try to be "smart" with the cursor position and indentation.

Right now, it supports vim, shell scripts, python, ruby and all the languages that use '//'.